# How to convert a list to a comma separated string?

Tags: python

Using a for loop I get the data:

```
58738121385139B
9135A4251EF0
2B631B53C383
```

I'm trying to get this data into one line separated by commas using

```
a = ', '.join(b);
```

but I get a comma after every character 5,8,7,3,8,1,2,1...
Please tell me how to get data `58738121385139B,9135A4251EF0,2B631B53C383` of this type.

Comment: What is in `b`. What's the type of `b`?

Comment: It looks like `b` is a string, not a list.

Comment: If you want to separate at the spaces use `str.split`:  `', '.join(b.split(" "))`

Comment: if ```b == 58738121...```,  couldn't you just ```a = ", ".join(b.split(" "))``` or even ```a = b.replace(" ", ",")```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- depends on your result and description, I guess your code is something like:

```
b = """58738121385139B
9135A4251EF0
2B631B53C383"""
print(', '.join(b))
result:
5, 8, 7, 3, 8, 1, 2, 1, 3, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, B, 
, 9, 1, 3, 5, A, 4, 2, 5, 1, E, F, 0, 
, 2, B, 6, 3, 1, B, 5, 3, C, 3, 8, 3
```

- you should use `split` to achieve it

```
print(', '.join(b.split("\n")))
result:
58738121385139B, 9135A4251EF0, 2B631B53C383
```

- Next time pls post your whole code to give us a MRE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not let us try to **guess** your code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your string consists of space-separated chunks of data,
You could try this:

```
a = b.replace(" ", ",")
```